# Unable to scrape the real-time price of bitcoin using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the real-time price of bitcoin. The price of bitcoin changes almost every 5 seconds on the website but in my code, it's not updating and remains the same as the first price scraped by the code. Can you help me why this is happening?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/'

for i in range(100):
    response = requests.get(url,  headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find('span' ,attrs={"class" : "cmc-details-panel-price__price"})
    print (price)
    time.sleep(20)
```

My output:

```
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span> 
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span> 
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
<span class="cmc-details-panel-price__price">$18,106.79</span>
```

Comment: The site is using live update, I guess some javascript etc. Everytime you refresh the site you will get the same value and then the site fires a trigger to update the value.
Since your request can't wait or interact with javascript on the site it always gets the first value on the load.

Comment: That data comes from a websocket, so use that. Otherwise you're wasting tons of resource and your prices lag behind real-time.

Answer (score 1):

The site is using live update, I guess some javascript. Everytime you refresh the site you will get the same value and then the site fires a trigger to update the value. Since your request can't wait or interact with javascript on the site it always gets the first value on the load.

My advice is to use an API, it's more efficient than scraping websites.
The first Google search gives: https://www.coindesk.com/coindesk-api as a free Bitcoin API.

See if their API endpoint: https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json
gives what you need, and then just parse the JSON.

Edit: Read the terms on their page.

Answer (score 0):

API is better but If you still want to scrape it, here's how you can do it using Google search results:

```py
import time, requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
      "User-Agent":
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
  }

# check 100 times (or use while loop instead)
for _ in range(100):
  
  html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+usd', headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

  print(soup.select_one('.SwHCTb').text)
  time.sleep(20) # sleep for price to change
```

Output:

```nolang
58,654.40
58,654.40
58,654.40
58,654.40
58,594.20
58,594.20
58,594.20
58,586.30
58,586.30
...
```

---

Alternatively, you can get this information by using the [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference, in this case, is that you don't have to figure out how to bypass blocks from Google.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "bitcoin usd",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

print(results['answer_box']['result'])

# 60,571.40 United States Dollar
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.